# Unable to extract item title in Amazon

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

When I'm trying to know the Title of `Sony` Headset using the below code, the result of code is `None`.

```
import requests    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Sony-Noise-Cancelling-Headphones- 
       WH1000XM3/dp/B07G4MNFS1/ref=sxin_0_ac_d_rm?ac_md=0-0-c29ueQ%3D%3D- 
       ac_d_rm&keywords=sony&pd_rd_i=B07G4MNFS1&pd_rd_r=3e6d5325-8ee4-4ba8-a84f- 
       1b7cf2ce98bf&pd_rd_w=BVSFq&pd_rd_wg=I0LMZ&pf_rd_p=e2f20af2-9651-42af-9a45- 
       89425d5bae34&pf_rd_r=VGT25BXXZNDE3B61A994&psc=1&qid=1577253649&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER'

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)    
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
soup.prettify()

#print(soup)

title = soup.find_all('span', {'id':'productTitle'})                        

print(title, len(title))
```

Current Output is :

```
[ ] 0
```

Comment: "productTitle" is the ID, not the class: ```soup.find("span", {"id": "productTitle"})```

Comment: even though when i write id not class , it will show up 0 [ ] the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent the last two hours trying to scrape that title with BeautifulSoup. I tried scraping other elements on the page. No success. I tried sending the raw content to file and that broke due to the presence of strange characters.

I tried Ahmed's answer and still got none. I tried a bunch of other solutions I found online and still got none. I can't for the life of me figure out how to use `BeautifulSoup` to scrape this.

I know you use Selenium, so here is the Selenium solution.

```
from selenium import webdriver
bot = webdriver.Chrome()
bot.get("https://www.amazon.com/Sony-Noise-Cancelling-Headphones-WH1000XM3/dp/B07G4MNFS1/ref=sxin_0_ac_d_rm?ac_md=0-0-c29ueQ==-ac_d_rm&keywords=sony&pd_rd_i=B07G4MNFS1&pd_rd_r=3e6d5325-8ee4-4ba8-a84f-1b7cf2ce98bf&pd_rd_w=BVSFq&pd_rd_wg=I0LMZ&pf_rd_p=e2f20af2-9651-42af-9a45-89425d5bae34&pf_rd_r=VGT25BXXZNDE3B61A994&psc=1&qid=1577253649&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER")
title = bot.find_element_by_id('productTitle').text
print(title)
bot.close()
```

Comment: @Xosrov comment works fine. Just add an user-agent header and use find or select_one to return single node and .text to extract the actual tag value.

Comment: @Matthew Gaiser i pretty much appreciate your valuable time to support me with that issue and if you like SONY wh-1000, the merry Christmas will send it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/Sony-Noise-Cancelling-Headphones-WH1000XM3/dp/B07G4MNFS1/ref=sxin_0_ac_d_rm?ac_md=0-0-c29ueQ==-ac_d_rm&keywords=sony&pd_rd_i=B07G4MNFS1&pd_rd_r=3e6d5325-8ee4-4ba8-a84f-1b7cf2ce98bf&pd_rd_w=BVSFq&pd_rd_wg=I0LMZ&pf_rd_p=e2f20af2-9651-42af-9a45-89425d5bae34&pf_rd_r=VGT25BXXZNDE3B61A994&psc=1&qid=1577253649&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("span", {'id': 'productTitle'}):
    print(item.get_text(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
Sony Noise Cancelling Headphones WH1000XM3: Wireless Bluetooth Over the Ear Headphones with Mic and Alexa voice control - Industry Leading Active Noise Cancellation - Black
```

Run Code Online: [Click Here](https://repl.it/@AmericanY/Omar)

Comment: You could also get if from meta ```title = soup.find_all('meta', {'name': 'title'})```

Comment: @Xosrov you should know the difference between `<script>` tag which is rendered via `JavaScript` and normal elements.